# Is there a quick way to get titlesec "simple mode" functionality in memoir class?

Tags: latex, memoir

Memoir class doesn't play nice with the titlesec package. Memoir has all the functionality of titlesec, but it doesn't seem to have a nice "simple mode" analogue. So in titlesec (with the article document class) I could just use `\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}` and that was that. If I wanted to do the same thing with memoir, it looks like I have to go through redefining all the section heading formatting and spacing itself?

Am I missing a quick way to replicate [small,compact] in memoir?

The point is not that I don't know how to get memoir to do this stuff. The point is that memoir is missing the "quick options" mode that titlesec had. If all I want to do is make all the section headings a little smaller the [small,compact] options when calling the package was fine. To do this in memoir takes a lot more work, going through all the options manually. Is this true or am I missing a memoir version of the quick options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}` will now work in memoir. I'm sure it didn't always work, but it does now. So the answer to my question is yes, there is a quick way to do it: use the titlesec package.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the memoir documentation. You can do this by opening a command prompt and entering `texdoc memman`

Specifically, see Chapter 8, which says:

> 8.1 Introduction In this chapter I first discuss the various kinds of
>   divisions within a book and the
>   commands for typesetting these. After
>   that I describe the class methods for
>   modifying the appearance of the
>   chapter and other sectional headings.
>   The facilities described here provide
>   roughly the same as you would get if
>   you used the titlesec [Bez99] and
>   sectsty [McD98] packages together; the
>   commands are different, though.

The memoir documentation is *very* good. You will most likely find everything you need in that document. It hasn't failed me yet.

Comment: I have two versions of memman. In one, the relevant chapter is Ch.6 and in the other it is Ch.10. (The latest version has it as Ch.6)

I know memoir has the resources of titlesec and secsty. What it seems to be missing is titlesec's quick "package options" method of changing lots of things quickly. (Section 2 of titlesec.pdf)

If I need to, I am fully aware that memman can teach me how to change everything I want. But, I was asking about a specific, quick, easy option that memoir seems to be missing.